# How to have program wide constant variables

Tags: c#

I have a c# program and I have some constant variables that I want to be accessible throughout the program. I won't need to change them at any point.

I have tried a static class and that worked well. I declared a 'static class' and had my variables inside as 'public static'.

The problem came when I wanted to use these unchanging variables in a case statement. Since this only accepts consts, it didn't work out too well.

The question is this: if I have a static class which does not have static variables within it, will this work just as well? This is going from `public static` to `public const`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes it will work just as well.

Comment: `static` and `const` don't exclude each other. You can simply use `public const` and it will be static automatically. But of course this depends on the type of the property. `const` can only be compile time constants such as integer or floating point values and strings, but no objects that need to be constructed.

Comment: @harold yes realized it after posting and just edited my comment.

Comment: "constant" "variables", Do you mean constants or variables? Making them global is one thing but be sure to use the right terms to get the best help.

Comment: If you make them `const` instead of just `static`, then yes you can use them in switch-statements, but you can no longer change them, and depending on whether you share this library with public constants, it may or may not be a good idea to make them constant either. Are they **really** constants? Such as "7 days in a week" constants? Or are they going to change in the near future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `const`s by default are `static`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Const can't be variables, they must be literals. If you're trying to assign a variable to the const such as a class you made then you have to keep it as static readonly. If you mean to assign a literal such as a number or a string then const is just fine.

A few examples:

```
public const int Number = 1; // this works; 1 is a literal
public const int Number = SomeClass.SomeProperty; // this does not work
public const int Number = SomeClass.SomeConst; // this works

public const SomeClass Var = new SomeClass(); // does not work
public const string Var = "test"; // this works as "test" is a literal.
```

If you are not using literals youre better of doing:

```
public static readonly SomeClass Var = new SomeClass ();
```

If you are using numeric literals another option is the enum which is basically a static class with some added features.

```
public enum MyConstants
{
    VarOne, // defaults to 0
    VarTwo, // defaults to next number (1)
    VarThree // defaults to next number (2)
}
```